# Why is intl_error_name returning undefined function?

Tags: php

I'm trying to call the PHP function [`intl_error_name()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intl-error-name.php) but it's returning a

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function.

```
function ErrorHandler($errno , $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext)
{
    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
        return;
    }
    echo intl_error_name($errno);
}
set_error_handler("ErrorHandler");

trigger_error("Test");
```

The documentation seems pretty straightforward.

Do I need to enable any extensions in order to use this? I tried enabling `extension=php_intl.dll` but it didn't work.
I'm using PHP version 5.5.12.

Comment: do you actually have that dll? is it the right compile version (e.g. ts v.s. nts). does it up show up in `phpinfo()`?

Answer (score 1):

you first need to install the PHP library to use this function.

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.requirements.php

Comment: Ok thanks. It's not worth it. I was just trying to get the friendly error name for my logs without using reflection. I will just add a switch case instead.

Comment: I would also prefer that, as including extra libraries would just slow down the whole process.